# Using Java generics to explicitly specify the type of collection returned and the type of the collection's elements

Tags: java, generics

As the title says.

Suppose I have a method that can convert a JSON array string to a Java collection, and it can specify the type of elements in the collection.
For example:

```
// variable 'json' is a String, like "[{...}, {...}, ...]"
List<Person> persons = MyUtil.convert(json, List.class, Person.class);
Set<Address> set = MyUtil.convert(json, Set.class, Address.class);
```

At present, the method signature I defined looks like this:

```
public static <C extends Collection<E>, E> C convert(String content, Class<C> collectionClass, Class<E> elementClass) {
    ....
}
```

There is a warning when I use this method:

> Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.List' to 'java.util.List<my.package.Person>'

I can understand why this warning appears, but I don't know how to optimize my method signature. (except using @SuppressWarnings)

Can I explicitly declare the returned collection and the type of its elements?
Maybe it looks like this:

```
public static C<E> convert(String content, Class<C> collectionClass, Class<E> elementClass) {
    ...
}
```

(Of course, I know it's completely impossible to compile, I just want to give an example.)

---

Thanks very much for [Donat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61410606/9298247).
I tried both ways:

```java
private static <C extends Collection<E>, E> C convert(String content, Supplier<C> supplier, Class<E> element) {
    ...
}

private static <C extends Collection<E>, E> C convert(String content, Class<C> collection, Class<E> element) {
    ...
}
```

Calling them:

```java
List<Person> l0 = convert("...", ArrayList::new, Person.class);  // No warning
List<Person> l1 = convert("...", ArrayList.class, Person.class); // Unchecked warning
```

Yeah, the problem resolved, but I'm still confused. The return value declarations of these two methods are the same. Why do they cause different results?

Comment: Why? Are you really planning on returning different collection types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better pass a collection factory to the method.

```
public static <C extends Collection<E>, E> C convert(String content, Supplier<C> collectionFactory, Class<E> elementClass) {
  C collection = collectionFactory.get();
  ...
  return collection;
}
```

You can invoke it for example like this:

```
List<Integer> list = convert("", ArrayList::new, Integer.class);
```

The main cause for using a supplier is: With a class it would be a diffcult to make a new instance in the body of the method. You cannot depend on the existence of a parameterless constructor. You will get uncecked warnings or must extend the signature with an Exception to be thrown.

Why the unchecked warning when calling your method? This is because you would have to pass a class of type `Class<ArrayList<Integer>>` in my example. But this make no sense. I think the type variable for `Class` has to be a real class (reifiable) like `ArrayList`. There is no class like `ArrayList<Integer>` because generics will be removed by the compiler. So this class value could not be distinguished from e. g. `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @Aslan Nice to hear, would you please give the solved state to my answer then

Comment: thank you very much for solving the warning problem for me. Do you have time to explain to me why using `Supplier` can eliminate the warning?